# OpenGL-ES finding the right coordinates (Translations etc...)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, coordinates

How can I correctly figure out what values I must use for gl.glTranslatef(x,y,z), and similar methods. Example: I've got an square, and want to display it in the upper left corner, at about 1/4th of the screen. I figured it would be glTranslate() with values -0.5 and 0.5, but this doens't display where I expected it.
So basically I wan't to know how to find the right coordinates for objects in OpenGL-ES.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately haven't developed opengl-es content for android yet, but AFAIK you need to convert screen coordinates (e.g. upper left corner on your screen) to world coordinates(coordinates in your 3D world in OpenGL).

For 3D you could do this would be through ray projection. You will find plenty of examples through [google search](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=convert%20screen%20coordinates%20to%20world%20coordinates&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) and maybe a OpenGL implementation too.

For 2D you can get away bit using an orthogonal projection matrix(with no perspective distortion basically) and rotating it as needed (e.g. for lanscape mode):

```
// Initialize your projection matrix - current number are half the dimensions for the G1 I borrowed(320x480)
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrthof(-240.0f, 240.0f, -160.0f, 160.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

// Rotate everything by 90 degrees
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(-90.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you, I looked and changed to orthographic projection, since i'm using 2D. Helped alot !